# wget and pipe to tar in the background

Tags: tar, gzip, wget, pipe

I am trying to download a large file which is `.tar.gz` and *(> 2GB)* in size. The bash script also does lots of other things, so I want to kick off the download and then continue processing other commands in the bash script. I am using `wget` and piping to `tar` and running it in the background with `&`.

```
wget -q "https://download-of-large-file-here.tar.gz" | tar xz &
# other commands here
```

However, this is breaking with:

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to instruct `wget` to write to STDOUT, you do this by passing `-O -` to wget, otherwise it will save the file to disk. `tar` is failing because as executed it's expecting something from STDIN.

This should work:

```
wget -q -O - "https://download-of-large-file-here.tar.gz" | tar xz &
```

Where `-q` suppresses the default progress information from STDOUT and `-O -` sets the output file to STDOUT.

Comment: This works, but the `wget` and `tar` process never seem to terminate. See a screenshot from `htop`. http://i.imgur.com/xwHmg8D.png

Comment: Does `tar` ever finish extracting? What happens when you run the commands separately?

(e.g. `wget -O "test.tar.gz" "https://download-of-large-file-here.tar.gz"`, then `tar xz test.tar.gz`)